# how to construct an array by row in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to construct an array using

```
> byrow=TRUE
```

inside of

```
> array()
```

But this function is not available.

For example: 
I type in

```
y<-array(1:24,c(4,3,2))
y
```

I get

```
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    5    9
[2,]    2    6   10
[3,]    3    7   11
[4,]    4    8   12

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   13   17   21
[2,]   14   18   22
[3,]   15   19   23
[4,]   16   20   24
```

But I want the numbers to be arranged by row.
So I tried

```
y<-array(1:24,c(4,3,2),byrow=TRUE)
```

But I got

> Error in array(1:24, c(4, 3, 2), byrow = TRUE) : 
>       unused argument (byrow = TRUE)

How can I achieve what I want?

Also, how to arrange the numbers by the other dimensions?

Comment: `array` does not have a byrow argument. See `?array`.

Comment: thanks, I see. but how can I achieve my purpose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `aperm` to transpose the array...

```
aperm(array(1:24,c(3,4,2)), c(2,1,3))
```